# Excel 2007 I need to be able to enter data in a cell on one sheet and have that populate on a different sheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Thank you in advance, I am attempting to have a workbook that on the 1st sheet has cells that I need to populate with the data I enter on the 2nd sheet.
There is no calculations that will be performed just simple text entry.

Comment: I think you need to show what you have tried, what you have read, and where you got stuck. This sounds like you simply need to go to sheet one, type "=" and click on the relevant cell on sheet 2. Or research "3D functions in Excel". Search first, then ask - you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

For an Excel formula that needs to reference a cell in a different worksheet in the same workbook, use the following format for your formula.
`SheetName!CellAddress`.

Note: For worksheet names that include one or more spaces, you will need to enclose it in single quotation marks. The following is a formula that refers to a cell on a sheet by the name of Monthly Sales: `=B4*’Monthly Sales’!A12`.

You can find pretty interesting stuff about excel with [a little bit of googling](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1604/excel_how_to_reference_cells_in_other_worksheets/)